# Relay mutation. FatQuery. Ask all fields in REQUIRED_CHILDREN

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

My question is: i have a mutations config where i have a REQUIRE_CHILDREN config with children array of queries. How can i get all possible fields from a payload object?

```
{
 type: 'REQUIRED_CHILDREN',
 children: [
  Relay.QL`
   fragment on MyPayload {
     me {
       id
       ...others field
     }
   }`]
```

So how can i ask all possible fields from `me` object? If i point only `fragment on MePayload { me }` object relay still returns me `me { id }`. I want relay to return me all fields in `me` object. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't - your client code needs to specify all the fields you want to fetch explicitly. Those fields are then statically validated by the `babel-relay-plugin`, etc.

You probably don't want to be using `REQUIRED_CHILDREN` either, by the way. That's only useful to fetch fields that are *only* accessible in the `onSuccess` callback of the mutation, and therefore are never written to the Relay store and accessible to Relay containers...

Comment: The thing is i want to send a request to my server and get back some data(not through relay). For example: i have a friends form, and i have an endpoint for getting initial variables from it. So my flow is: i send a request to the server and i get initialData for my form and then i need to dispatch that data(for getting in in my component). So how can i get full data from `const initialData = await MyMytation();`?

Comment: If by "endpoint" you mean a non-GraphQL endpoint to fetch initial data, you can get that information however you like (insert-favourite-ajax-library-here). Then just populate that in your form and provided those variables to your mutation, etc.

Comment: If by "endpoint" you mean you have some kind of "draft form data" in your GraphQL schema, you can fetch that data the same way you'd fetch any other GraphQL data in Relay: set up a container with a fragment, nest that container under a Route, etc.